# Is it possible to override css in Disqus 2012 using javascript after the Disqus thread has loaded?

Tags: javascript, css, disqus, overriding

I have updated to Disqus 2012 and my CSS overrides no longer work as Disqus is now loaded in an iframe.

However, I can override CSS using the inspector after the Disqus thread has loaded, so I am wondering if it would be possible to do this using javascript that fires just after the Disqus thread/iframe has loaded onto the page?

Answer (score 0):

Disqus 2012 is indeed inside of an iframe, and there is no way to target iframes using CSS statements outside of the `#disqus_thread` attribute.

Sorry, but if you wish to use CSS right now in Disqus, you'll have to revert back to the classic Disqus. Don't worry, though, because CSS is a feature that is being demanded by many Disqus users, including me.

Comment: And here we are a year later :(

Comment: And here we are two years later :(

Comment: And here we are three years later :(

Comment: And here I am from 12 years into the future - still no luck.